# How to add quotes to string in a batch script

Tags: batch-file

Basically I have a variable that has a string in it that is the path to an uninstall program.  Sometimes when the variable gets returned it'll return something like

```
"C:/path to uninstall file/uninstall.exe"
```

While other times it may return

```
MsiExec.exe /I{regkeyhere}
```

Both of those are fine, it's when something like this get's returned

```
C:/path to uninstall file/uninstall.exe
```

Where there are no quotes in a file path that causes the call function to fail.  Is there anyway to check if the variable begins with a C: and if it does add a quote to the beginning and the end of the string?  If it begins with anything other than C: then it doesn't matter, its only if it has a file path with spaces in it that it breaks down.  I've tried a couple different string replaces, but for some reason it always breaks down.

Comment: Sorry :(  but you should use Powershell, Basic or Perl rather than batch! Deleted my answer for some reason!

Comment: Why would you delete your answer?  And this is being done on government computers, I'm limited by policy what we can and cannot do.  So I don't have a choice in that matter, I'm working with what tools I have to complete the job, either way, the other guy answered the question and his fix worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a caret to escape the quotes:

```
if "%variable:~0,2%"=="C:" set variable=^"%variable%^"
```

**EDIT:** I realised there would be an error if quotes already existed, so this code will create a test variable (with quotes removed) to test the variable first. This code also will not add quotes if there are no spaces.

If it starts with `C:`, ( If there are spaces don't add quotes, else, add quotes ).

```
set test=%uninstallStr:"=%
if "%test:~0,2%"=="C:" (
    if "%test: =%"=="%test%" (
      set uninstallStr=%test%
    ) else (
      set uninstallStr=^"%test%^"
    )
)
```

**EDIT 2:** I realised there would be more problems with poison characters like `<` and `>`, so this code will escape those poison characters first before processing..

```
set ^"uninstallStr=^"C:\Program Files ^<x86^>\Price Check by AOL\uninstall.exe^"^"
echo %uninstallStr%

set "test=%uninstallStr:"=%"
set "test=%test:<=^<%"
set "test=%test:>=^>%"
if "%test:~0,2%"=="C:" (
    if "%test: =%"=="%test%" (
      set uninstallStr=%test%
    ) else (
      set uninstallStr=^"%test%^"
    )
)

echo %uninstallStr%
pause
```

Comment: This is what I ended up with `if "%uninstallStr:~0,2"=="C:" set uninstallStr=^"%uninstallStr%^"` except it's not adding quotes

Comment: You didn't add a percent sign between `~0,2` and `"==`. It should be `if "%uninstallStr:~0,2%"=="C:" set uninstallStr=^"%uninstallStr%^"`

Comment: ok, only one issue, if there are no spaces in the filepath, apparently you cannot use quotes to uninstall the product.  So how can I check to make sure that the string starts with C: AND has spaces in it before adding the quotes?

Comment: Added new code which should solve the problem.. If you want it to work for any drive, you can modify it to find a colon as the second character by replacing the second line with `if "%test:~1,1%"==":" (`.

Comment: seems to be working, although sublime doesn't like the syntax of opening a quote and not closing it lol

Comment: @Flynn Wait.. What do you mean?

Comment: `set test=%uninstallStr:"=%`  only has one quote, I wasn't sure if that was the way it was supposed to be or if thats a syntax error.

Comment: Oh `%uninstallstr:"=%` means 'Replace all occurrences of `"` in `%uninstallstr%` with (nothing)'. This will just remove all quotes. For example, `%variable:original=replace%` means to replace all occurrences of 'original' in variable with 'replace'.

Comment: As another example, in my third line, `if "%test: =%"=="%test%" (` checks whether `%test%` with the spaces removed is still the same. This will check whether there are spaces in `%test%`.

Comment: what i meant was does it have to be escaped?  i know any other language would parse it and fail because it's not closed, the quote is an operational character, and if used as a string should it be escaped?

Comment: I probably can't give you a good explanation on this, but whatever that is between the two percent signs (inclusive) should be processed first, so it removes the quotes first and whatever that is run with the `set` command does not have any quotes in it.

Comment: ah, well i just tested it and it's not inserting quotes around strings

Comment: Do the strings start with `C:` and do they have spaces?

Comment: there are strings that start with C: that have spaces and ones that do not.  the ones with spaces need to have quotes around them, the ones without could not have quotes

Comment: The code should do that.. What results are you getting? Is it not adding quotes at all?

Comment: just ran it, did an echo of the string before and after, they both match `C:\Program Files <x86>\Price Check by AOL\uninstall.exe` is the exact string, before that's what it looks like, after that's what it still looks like